# Redirect only home page

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I need to redirect only http://shop.test.com to http://www.test.com/fedex-orders/

Just homepage. Nothing else. ie http://shop.test.com/?page=blog should NOT redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a location like so:

```
location = / {
   if ($args !~* .+ ) { 
      return 301 http://www.test.com/fedex-orders;
   }
}
```

Basically that location matches the '/' only, so any config in there only applies to the homepage

since anything with get arguments is the same file for the webserver you need the extra if, that redirects only if the regex doesn't match.